# yet another cloud plugin in jenkins is not connecting to tcp://docker:2376 using ec2 instance

Tags: docker, jenkins, networking, continuous-integration, cloud

Iam not able to connect to tcp://docker:2376 in yet another plugin on jenkins. Jenkins in running in docker container in the port 8080. A docker dind is exposed with tcp port 2376 in another dind container. sharing a screenshot of the error here.

[image]

error log

Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.BadRequestException: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.

```
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.com.github.dockerjava.netty.handler.HttpResponseHandler.channelRead0(HttpResponseHandler.java:93)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.com.github.dockerjava.netty.handler.HttpResponseHandler.channelRead0(HttpResponseHandler.java:32)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:384)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:355)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:282)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:223)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1429)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:947)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:822)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:466)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
at com.github.kostyasha.yad_docker_java.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Were you able to fix it ? Having the same problem.

Comment: @Miguelme yes i have shared the answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve the issue connect docker.sock volume to host ie, while starting jenkins docker container

```
docker container run --name jenkins-blueocean --rm --detach --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro --publish 8080:8080 --publish 50000:50000 jenkinsci/blueocean
```